# Definir Dictionary como constante

Tags: c#

Segue o código abaixo:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "tipo1", "dada65d" },
    { "tipo2", "546541354765321" },
    { "tipo3", "klwoiqyhalwtbfowh" }
};
```

Como posso declarar a classe `Dictionary` como constante (`const`)?

Comment: Seria legal que pudesse ser `const` mesmo, mas sei das limitações do CLR e o ganho não seria tão grande.

Answer (score 2):

Deixei outra alternativa utilizando `readonly`

```
private readonly static Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "tipo1", "dada65d" },
    { "tipo2", "546541354765321" },
    { "tipo3", "klwoiqyhalwtbfowh" }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Para estes casos eu normalmente uso um enum, porque é, de uma certa maneira, um dicionário constante.

Mas de qualquer maneira podes utilizar readonly para que apenas seja escrito no construtor e não em outros sítios.